# Uploading an image to a database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to upload images to a database where the image will only echo out if it is by the user but it doesn't work and it doesn't give me any errors

```
<?php

session_start();

    $pic = $_FILES['pic'];
    $submit = $_POST['post'];
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];

    if($submit){
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123");
        if($connect){
            $database = mysql_select_db("phplogin");
            if($database){
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO images(image, user) VALUES ($pic, $user)");
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE user = '$user'");
                $data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
                echo $data2['image'];
            } else {
                die("Couldn't connect to the database please try again, if you fail to connect again please contact me");
            }
        } else {
            die("Couldn't connect to the database please try again, if you fail to connect again please contact me");
        }
    }



?>
```

Comment: your `$pic` variable is the file item's info array, its just an array of information about the file not the actual file contents

Comment: how do i make it the files contents

Comment: Learn how to do basic debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the file's contents first then insert them into the database. Also your query does not close the variables off in single quotes.

```
//Need to get contents then escape any characters that match
//mysql query elements like quotes etc.
$contents = mysql_real_escape_string( file_get_contents($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']) );
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO images(image, user) VALUES ('$contents', '$user')");
if($result === FALSE){
   //insert failed echo error and die
   echo mysql_error();
   die;
}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE user = '$user'");
$data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $data2['image'];
```

Note that you should be using mysqli and prepared statements instead. mysql_* and the mysql class are depreciated, and using prepared statements are better for preventing injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for that it works but now to get the image on another page do i just query the database again then echo it out?

Comment: @user3470226, yes to get it back out for displaying just create a script that just looks up the row, sends the header, and then echos the image data out, then instead of using a url that points to a file, just use the url for the script

Comment: Thanks for that wasn't to sure on that part.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the image name in the database table.

```
$pic = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
```

You should save the image in the folder in your server using copy() php function

```
copy($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'],'path_to_folder/'.$_FILES['name']);
```

Comment: he wants the image saved in the database itself.

Comment: we cant save the image in the database, we can only save the name, which i already explained above clearly.

Comment: You most certainly can save images to a database, use a longblob column and get the files contents and insert it into that column. Though there is a question of wither or not you should do it.

Comment: @Patrick Evans. i thought, there is no way. As per your suggestion , i got a way. ok , i will try like you said.